# Upload multiple images along with other parameters

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, server

How to upload array of images along with other parameters, Images are captured with device camera and needed to be uploaded.
So far I've tried code below :

converting Captured image into NSData :

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i< imageArray.count ; i++)
    {
        UIImage *images = [imageArray objectAtIndex :i];
        NSData *Datas = UIImagePNGRepresentation(images);
        [Images addObject:Datas];

    }
```

Retrieve saved array of images :

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    arrayOfImages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"image"];
```

Uploading Images to server:

```
      NSDictionary *params =@{ @"name":self->Name.text, @"contact_no":self->ContactNo.text,@"email_id":self->EmailId.text,@"s_date":Date,@"s_time":Time,@"streat":Street,@"city":City,@"state":State,@"zip":ZipCode};

NSData *uploadData = Data;
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url"];       

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSString *kNewLine = @"\r\n";

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

for (NSString *name in params.allKeys) {

    NSData *values = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", params[name]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@%@", boundary, kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"", name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kNewLine, kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:values];
    [body appendData:[kNewLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfImages.count ; i++)
        {
            uploadData = [arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:i];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file_name[]\""] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:uploadData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
                              {
                                  NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                  NSLog(@"%@",returnString);

}];
```

PHP code :

```
 $filesCount = count($_FILES['file_name']['name']);

 for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){

 $_FILES['file_name1']['name'] = time().'_'.$_FILES['file_name']['name'][$i];
 $_FILES['file_name1']['type'] = $_FILES['file_name']['type'][$I];
 $_FILES['file_name1']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'][$i];
 $_FILES['file_name1']['error'] = $_FILES['file_name']['error'][$i];
 $_FILES['file_name1']['size'] = $_FILES['file_name']['size'][$i]; 


  $config['upload_path'] = $upload_path;
  $config['allowed_types'] = '*';

 $this->load->library('upload');
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload('file_name1')){                    
               $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
 $name_array[] = $upload_data['file_name'];
 $fileName = $upload_data['file_name'];
 $images[] = $fileName;
            }else{
  $data['upload_errors'][$i] = $this->upload->display_errors();
}


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@“Your url”]];
       [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/html", nil];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:@"url"parameters:_paramaters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                                         {
                                             [formData appendPartWithFileData:imagedata name:@"filename" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                                         }
                                              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                                         {
                                                                      }
                                              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
                                         {
                                                                       }];

    [operation start];
```

You can use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager instead and the code is above and it worked for me.